# Incorporating offset into a sklearn Poisson Decision Tree regression in Python?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am looking at how best to reproduce something like this R-code in Python:

```
library(rpart) # "Recursive partitioning for classification, regression and survival trees". Default metric: Gini impurity
tree <- rpart(cbind(Exposure,ClaimNb) ~ Area + VehPower + VehAge + DrivAge 
              + BonusMalus + VehBrand + VehGas + Density + Region, dat, 
              method="poisson", control=rpart.control(maxdepth=3,cp=0.001))      
#            complexity-parameter cp is used to control the number of splits
```

Source: https://www.kaggle.com/floser/glm-neural-nets-and-xgboost-for-insurance-pricing/comments

Is there an elegant way of incorporating the offset (in this case Exposure) into a DecisionTreeRegressor?  Or am I just going to have to divide my response variable by the offset?

As an aside, the decision tree graphic in the link is really really good and seems to be difficult to reproduce in Python.  For one thing the sklearn decision trees don't seem to be able to cope with categorical variables unless you hot-encode them and I still haven't yet figured out how to get the variable names to display nicely in the decision tree.

Comment: h2o looks promising...